# Prove a linear functional attains its minimum

Tags: functional-analysis

*I am not familiar with functional analysis at all so I apologize beforehand if there is any conceptual mistake. The situation is as follows:

Let $H$ be a real Hilbert space, and let $l$ be a real-valued bounded linear functional on $H$ and $C$ be a closed and convex subset of $H$. Define
$f(v) = \frac{1}{2} \lVert v\rVert^2 - l(v)$.

Show that there exists a unique $u_0 \in C$ such that $f(u_0)= inf_{v \in C} f(v)$.

Now the immediate idea is to use Riesz representation theorem so that one has
$f(v) = \frac{1}{2} \langle v,v \rangle - \langle v,z \rangle $ for some unique $z \in H$. Then one can use Hilbert projection theorem to find a unique $u_0$ such that $ \langle \frac{1}{2}u_0 - z, \frac{1}{2}u_0 - z \rangle \lt \langle c - z,c - z \rangle$ holds on $c \in C$. Pick this $u_0$ as our candidate. Then one has
$f(u_0)=\frac{1}{2} \langle u_0,u_0 \rangle - \langle u_0,z \rangle = \langle u_0, \frac{1}{2}u_0 - z \rangle = \langle \frac{1}{2}u_0 - z, \frac{1}{2}u_0 - z \rangle + \langle \frac{1}{2}u_0 + z, \frac{1}{2}u_0 - z \rangle$.

This suggests $u_0$ is perhaps not the candidate, I try to play around with the inner products, but don't have a clue.

Comment: your functional $f$ is not linear...

Comment: @daw To think about I took the linearity for granted and was still trying to figure out why the theorems didn't work out as planned until now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $m=\inf_{f \in C} f(v)$. There is a sequence $(v_n)$ in $C$ such that $f(v_n) \to m$. Now $f(v_n)\ge \frac 1 2 \|v_n\|^{2}-\|l\|\|v_n\|$. Use the fact that $(f(v_n))$ is bounded to conclude that $\|v_n\|$ is bounded. Any bounded sequence in a Hilbert space has a weakly convergent subsequence. Suppose $v_{n_k} \to w$ weakly. Then $w \in C$ because  a closed convex set is also weakly closed. Let us show that $f(w)=m$.
Since $\frac 1 2 \|v_{n_k}\|^{2}-\langle v_{n_k}, z \rangle \to m $ and $\langle v_{n_k}, z \rangle \to \langle w, z \rangle$, it follows that $\|v_{n_k}\|$ converges to some limit $t$. Note that $\frac 1 2 t^{2}-\langle w, z \rangle = \lim [\frac 1 2 \|v_{n_k}\|^{2}-\langle v_{n_k}, z \rangle]=\lim f(v_{n_k})=m$, Finally, note that $ \langle w, u \rangle=\lim \langle v_{n_k}, u \rangle\le \lim \|v_{n_k}\|\|u\|=t\|u\|$ for al $u$, which implies $\|w\|\leq t$. Thus, $f(w)=\frac 1 2 \|w\|^{2}-l(w)\le \frac 1 2 t^{2}-l(w)=m$.